# Stored Procedure for apply order as per ID

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i have table like below, i want a stored procedure for update Order as Per Id(Primery key). currently i just inserted Order column
in a table, so i just want to order old items in database as per id.

for e.g. right now i have table like this

Table Name: ReportRule

```
id Order
-- ------
21  NULL
28  NULL
35  NULL
49  NULL
```

and i want to make it like below using stored procedure

```
id Order
-- ------
21  1   
28  2
35  3
49  4
```

so i just want to give a order starting from 1 as per ID ascending order
i want that result using stored procedure, please help.

Comment: hint : use rank function

Answer (score 2):

You can use an updatable CTE:

```
with toudpate as (
      select rr.*, row_number() over (order by id) as new_order
      from ReportRule rr
     )
update toupdate
    set [order] = new_order;
```

By the way, `order` is a very bad name for a column because it is a SQL keyword.

Comment: yes, my mistake. i will use as FieldOrder, but its not working

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a subquery with `ROW_NUMBER` and then `UPDATE ... FROM ...`

```
UPDATE dst
SET
  dst.[Order]=src.[Order]
FROM ReportRule dst
JOIN
  (
    SELECT ID,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID) [Order]
    FROM ReportRule
  ) src
ON dst.ID=src.ID
```

A variant without `ROW_NUMBER` (You can use it if you have an old version SQL Server)

```
UPDATE dst
SET
  dst.[Order]=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ReportRule src WHERE dst.ID>=src.ID)
FROM ReportRule dst
```

Try to use the next variant for MySQL

```
UPDATE ReportRule dst
SET
  dst.FieldOrder=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ReportRule src WHERE dst.ID>=src.ID)
```

Comment: @Badal Solanki - Do you use MSSQLServer or MySQL? I checked two queries and it works for MSSQLServer.

Comment: @Badal Solanki - Then you need to change the tag to MySQL.

Comment: @Badal Solanki - I've updated my answer. Try to use the last query.